# Wrong favicon displayed on Google's mobile SERP

Tags: seo, favicon

For some time now, Google has been displaying a website's favicon next to its title on the mobile SERP according to [this answer.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9290858)

But, for one website that I am managing, it is showing a completely different favicon. You can see it if you open the [following URL](https://www.google.com/search?ei=U9vgXZPLPMuGk74PyqKc6A8&q=hoofgroove&oq=hoofgroove) on a mobile device, I am talking about the orange one:

I am referring to the top result.

As you can see on the [website itself](https://www.hoofgroove.ch/), the favicon has been added correctly using the proper meta tag:

```
<link  rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://www.hoofgroove.ch/pub/media/favicon/default/favicon.ico" />
```

This is according to [Google's guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9290858).

Also, all the browsers are displaying the correct favicon, which is not the orange one but the black&red one.

This meta tag has been used for weeks and also the [favicon](https://www.hoofgroove.ch/pub/media/favicon/default/favicon.ico) has always been the correct one as far as I can tell.

But for some reason, Google is showing the wrong favicon on its mobile SERP.

Any ideas why?

Comment: I've seen this happening with other sites, and although i dont know why is happening the most logical fix will be for you to move your desired favicon in your root directory. https://www.hoofgroove.ch/favicon.ico and force crawl the homepage

Comment: Thanks, but I have already placed an additional favicon there some weeks ago: https://www.hoofgroove.ch/favicon.ico. However, due to some constraints our CMS is not letting us change the actual meta tag to reference that file. :(

Comment: Do you know where Google was getting the "wrong" favicon from? Was it an "old" favicon"? Was it another file on your site? Or had this "wrong" favicon/image never existed on your site?

Comment: @MrWhite it was definitely an old favicon, matter of fact it was the default one used by the CMS that we're using. But how exactly it happened I couldn't tell you as I wasn't the one to set up this installation, I only took it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3+ weeks it seems that Google has finally picked up the correct favicon. So my suggestion to anyone else facing the same problem would be to just wait it out, if you have double checked every other solution.